# Manual language translation in drupal website?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am developing the job portal website in multilingual. right now site have two (German&English) languages. and have static & dynamic content. I have to use manual language translator text (client will provide the content for static). not a auto translating option like google translator.

1. How to translate the entire site in multilanguage, Handling dynamic data, menus etc.
2. What are the modules will you suggest for this

Please help us on this, and let me know if you need further details.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is way too broad; as per this site's FAQ, questions should be specific and should not be the kind that could be answered by an entire book.  In your case, the book is *Drupal Multilingual Websites* by Kristin Pol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the core modules "Locale" and "Content Translation". There's additional contributed modules like [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) or in short i18n

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "dynamic data". So I can't answer that part of your question.